# Alternative to Jquery Ajax load method?

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to run comment section and replies with ajax via file named comment_frame.php. Inside this file is html form to send replies on comments and here comes my problem - if someone send replies from bla-bla.php, wof-wof.php or whatever is redirected to comment_frame.php..

I tried to fix this with $('form').submit(function... but the problem is because the form is saved only in comment_form.php and not in bla-bla.php, wof-wof.php files..

So.. Is there any alternative to Jquery Ajax load method?  Is there any other way to fix this  issue?

Thanks!

```
$str .= "<div class='status_post' onClick='javascript:toggle$id()'>
                        <div class='post_profile_pic'>
                            <img src='$profile_pic' width='50'>
                        </div>

                        <div class='posted_by' style='color:#ACACAC;'>
                            <a href='$added_by'> $first_name $last_name </a> $user_to &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;$time_message
                            $delete_button
                        </div>
                        <div id='post_body'>
                            $body
                            <br>
                            $imageDiv
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </div>

                        <div class='newsfeedPostOptions'>
                            Comments($comments_check_num)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class='post_comment' id='toggleComment$id' style='display:none;'>
                        <div id='show_comments$id'></div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>";
        }

        ?>

        <script>
             $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#show_comments<?php echo $id; ?>').load("comment_frame.php?post_id=<?php echo $id; ?>");
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. What are `bla-blah.php` and `wof-wof.php`? How do they relate to your comment form?

Comment: @Barmar bla-bla.php, wof-wof.php are just examples.. In a real scenario i have .php pages with blog posts and below these blog pots I have comment section (code above) and right there I have problem that is described above... – Kiki Miki 13 mins ago

Comment: So the issue is that you're embedding this comment code into lots of different pages, and when they submit the form you want them to be redirected to the original page, not to your page?

Comment: AJAX is the obvious solution, that's how services like Disqus work. An alternative is to use the HTTP referer, and redirect them back to that URL.